# Send mail by cron job in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cron

I want to send mail once in a per day by cpanel cron job not wordpress cron job.I have written mail send script in function.php file and run through wordpress cron job.It is working perfectly but issue with wordpress cron job is that when someone visit on site once then it will work.That'why I want to set it by cpanel cron job but I am unable to do this.I have no idea how to set it by cpanel and where put my mail script for this.This is my code in function.php

```
  if (!wp_next_scheduled('birthday_notification'))
{
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'birthday_notification');
}

add_action(birthday_notification,send_birthday_notification);

function my_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'birthday_notification');
}


function send_birthday_notification(){
wp_mail($to,$subject,$message);
}
```

Comment: check the given answer it should help you

Comment: please if my answer solved your question then mark as solution thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to create one file in WordPress root directory beside of `wp-config.php`
like for example `cron.php`

with this code

```
<?PHP 

 define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
 require('wp-load.php');  // this file load all Wordpress functions for you in your file 


/*

you can write all your Wordpress code here 

*/

?>
```

after this, you need to set corn in your Cpanel as you want and call this file

Comment: try removing this line  define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare send_birthday_notification() previously declared in function .php.I removed from function .php and declared in new page,hit url manually but not received any mail.

Comment: try to debug because you have an issue in your code. I just give you a way how to do it

Comment: <?PHP 

 //define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
 require('wp-load.php');  // this file load all Wordpress functions for you in your file 


if (!wp_next_scheduled('birthday_notification'))
{

  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'birthday_notification');
}

add_action(birthday_notification,send_birthday_notification);

function my_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'birthday_notification');
}

function send_birthday_notification(){

wp_mail($to,'Birthday Wish','Happy birthday');
}

?>I have create new page with this code.

Comment: your code is wrong. why are you scheduling the event again? how are you getting $to here ?

Comment: Can you modify my commented code?.I have set up cron like wget -q -O - https://example.com/cron.php in cpanel.

Comment: first of all, what are you trying to do explain here because i just gives you an answer of how can you run corn from cpanel for Wordpress

Comment: my requirement is sent  a notification mail to admin 7 days before for upcoming users birthday.I have fetched user data which birthday coming in 7 days.I want to run a cron job for this.

Comment: ok then show me the code that you fetched user data and I will edit it and send to you please do fast or give me you your skype id we can take call fast and finish this matter

Comment: function send_birthday_notification(){
global $wpdb;
$data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM 3g0jbr30c_gf_entry_meta1 where (meta_key=1 and  meta_value=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY))");
foreach($data as $values)
{
$Name=$fname.''.$lname;
$email='xxxx@gmail.com';
$subject='Birthday Notification';
$message = "Name:$Name<br />";
$message .= "Date to open card:$dob<br />";
$site_name='Sale United FC';
$from='office@example.com';
$headers = array('From: '.$site_name.' <'.$from.'>');
wp_mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
 }
}

Comment: your code is ok if you give the proper email address and one more thing can you debug wp_mail() function and one try with simple PHP mail function and also check your spam folder